# Neovim Lua isdirectory vim function

Tags: lua, neovim

I am hoping to set up keymaps for when I am in a git directory and when I am not. Maybe now that I am using Lua that maybe I cannot do this like this. Any help would be appreciated.

```lua
if vim.fn.isdirectory('.git') then
  map('n', '<leader>t', '<cmd>lua require(\'telescope.builtin\').git_files({hidden = true})<CR>', options)
else
  map('n', '<leader>e', '<cmd>lua require(\'telescope.builtin\').find_files({hidden = true})<CR>', options)
end
```

Seems like if always hits and never the else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:h isdirectory

> **isdirectory({directory})**
>
> *isdirectory()*        The result is a Number,
> which is non-zero when a directory        with the name {directory} exists.
> If {directory} doesn't        exist, or isn't a directory, the result is
> FALSE.  {directory}       is any expression, which is used as a String.

:h FALSE

> For boolean operators Numbers are used.  Zero is FALSE, non-zero is
> TRUE. You can also use |v:false| and |v:true|.  When TRUE is returned
> from a function it is the Number one, FALSE is the number zero.

Make sure that `FALSE` is actually `false`. It is probably `0` which would be a true value in Lua.
In Lua any values but false or nil are true.

So ideally check `if vim.fn.isdirectory('.git') ~= 0 then`